# Морда была счастливой или была счастливая?

Tags: грамотная-речь, падежи, выбор-варианта

Как правильно написать (речь о собаке):
**Морда у него была счастливой и довольной** или **счастливая и довольная**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможны оба варианта, но лучше выбрать И.п.:

**Морда у него была счастливая и довольная.**

Это **разговорная** речь, кроме того, мы как бы **фиксируем** момент времени.

**Пояснение**

Розенталь http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/62.htm

Обычно  именительный падеж (**для существительных**)  указывает на устойчивый признак предмета, на **постоянно** присущую ему качественную характеристику, а творительный падеж – на **временный** признак.

**Имя прилагательное** в составном сказуемом  **обладает большей свободой в выборе формы творительного или именительного падежей**. **Но творительный падеж свойствен книжной речи, а именительный – разговорной.** Я бываю гадкая... (Л.Толстой). – Когда же я бываю любезным! (Тургенев). Мысль Викентия Алексеевича шла примерно теми же ходами, что и прохоровская, ассоциации были тождественными (В. Липатов). – Парень-то был ядреный, в плечах широкий (В. Белов).